# Accessing property of generic type in a function in c#

Tags: c#, generics

I need to have a interface that has generic methods. However each implementation of that interface will know its type.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var specificContext = new SpecificContext();

        var res = new SrvThatCantBeGeneric().GetValueFromSpecificContext(specificContext);
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }

}
public class SrvThatCantBeGeneric : ISrvThatCantBeGeneric
{
    public int GetValueFromSpecificContext<SpecificContext>(SpecificContext specificContext)
    {
        return specificContext.MyProperty; // <-- this is where it breaks
    }
}

public interface ISrvThatCantBeGeneric
{        
    int GetValueFromSpecificContext<T>( T specificContext);
}

public class SpecificContext
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; } = 42;
}
```

For some reason when I do it the above way it doesn't work and states that:

> 'SpecificContext' does not contain a definition for 'MyProperty' and no accessible extension method 'MyProperty' accepting a first argument of type 'SpecificContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Why is this happening and how to solve it?

I can fix it by moving definition of generic type like so:

```
public class SrvThatCantBeGeneric : ISrvThatCantBeGeneric<SpecificContext>
{
    public int GetValueFromSpecificContext(SpecificContext specificContext)
    {
        return specificContext.MyProperty; // <-- this is where it breaks
    }
}

public interface ISrvThatCantBeGeneric<T>
{        
    int GetValueFromSpecificContext( T specificContext);
}
```

but this breaks in another parts of code and is no go.

Edit: Simplification of my code

Comment: `SpecificContext` in `GetValueFromSpecificContext<SpecificContext>(BaseContext<SpecificContext> my)` does not represent the class `SpecificContext`. But it just represents the Generic Type same as `T` in common Generic declarations.. The actual type to this method is provided when you call the method.. as `obj.GetValueFromSpecificContext<SpecificType>(`

Comment: If your `T` of `GetValueFromSpecificContext` is going to be only `SpecificContext` or any derived class of `SpecificContext` then you need to have method as following.. `int GetValueFromSpecificContext<T>(BaseContext<T> my) where T : SpecificContext;` this way you can access `MyProperty` of `my` in the method body.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya so why does the second approach work? sorry for changing code after posting but I was able to simplify it much.

Comment: In the second approach when you do `ISrvThatCantBeGeneric<SpecificContext>` you are declaring that `SrvThatCantBeGeneric` class will implement the interface for type `SpecificContext` which is specific type not `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing:

```
public int GetValueFromSpecificContext<SpecificContext>(SpecificContext specificContext)
```

You "override" the scope and here `SpecificContext` is a generic type parameter that masks the class having this name, so it is the same as:

```
public int GetValueFromSpecificContext<T>(T specificContext)
```

Perhaps you wanted to write:

```
public interface ISrvThatCantBeGeneric
{
  int GetValueFromSpecificContext<T>(T specificContext) where T : SpecificContext;
}

public class SrvThatCantBeGeneric : ISrvThatCantBeGeneric
{
  public int GetValueFromSpecificContext<T>(T specificContext) where T : SpecificContext
  {
    return specificContext.MyProperty;
  }
}

public class SpecificContext
{
  public int MyProperty { get; set; } = 42;
}

public class SpecificContextChild : SpecificContext
{
  public SpecificContextChild()
  {
    MyProperty = 10;
  }
}
```

*Test*

```
var server = new SrvThatCantBeGeneric();
var context = new SpecificContextChild();
Console.WriteLine(server.GetValueFromSpecificContext(context));
```

*Output*

```
10
```

**Also you can promote interface and class as generics, and not the method itself**

In case it is relevant:

```
public interface ISrvThatCantBeGeneric<T> where T : SpecificContext
{
  int GetValueFromSpecificContext(T specificContext);
}

public class SrvThatCantBeGeneric<T> : ISrvThatCantBeGeneric<T> where T : SpecificContext
{
  public int GetValueFromSpecificContext(T specificContext)
  {
    return specificContext.MyProperty;
  }
}

public class SpecificContext
{
  public int MyProperty { get; set; } = 42;
}

public class SpecificContextChild : SpecificContext
{

  public SpecificContextChild()
  {
    MyProperty = 10;
  }
}

var server = new SrvThatCantBeGeneric<SpecificContextChild>();
var context = new SpecificContextChild();
Console.WriteLine(server.GetValueFromSpecificContext(context));
```

**Also if you prefer or need you can use an interface instead of the base class**

```
public interface IContext
{
  int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

*Non-generic class version:*

```
public interface ISrvThatCantBeGeneric
{
  int GetValueFromSpecificContext<T>(T specificContext) where T : IContext;
}

public class SrvThatCantBeGeneric : ISrvThatCantBeGeneric
{
  public int GetValueFromSpecificContext<T>(T specificContext) where T : IContext
  {
    return specificContext.MyProperty;
  }
}

public class SpecificContext : IContext
{
  public int MyProperty { get; set; } = 42;
}
```

*Generic class version:*

```
public interface ISrvThatCantBeGeneric<T> where T : IContext
{
  int GetValueFromSpecificContext(T specificContext);
}

public class SrvThatCantBeGeneric<T> : ISrvThatCantBeGeneric<T> where T : IContext
{
  public int GetValueFromSpecificContext(T specificContext)
  {
    return specificContext.MyProperty;
  }
}

public class SpecificContext : IContext
{
  public int MyProperty { get; set; } = 42;
}
```

Comment: each implementation of the interface will have completely different context. So using constraints will not work. I  need to look for different approach to avoid this issue.

Comment: @Icen Answer updated. To access MyProperty, you need to contrainst on the base class, or any interface instead, if you prefer. But the OOP pattern remains the same.

Comment: My goal was to have strongly typed list of steps (functions) that can be fetched from ICO container. It was very nice idea to solve issue of having dynamic signal flow in our process. So I had like IStep1:ISrvThatCantBeGeneric and IStep2:ISrvThatCantBeGeneric and then IOC had returend me proper implementation of each step based on type of the caller. All is working except you can't access context object as you don't know it's type.

Comment: @Icen I am sorry but I did not understand anything: I do not have the knowledge of the subject that you describe here with this vocabulary. But it seems that using an interface like exposed should solve your problem, therefore you can manipulate any object implementing this interface, regardless of class hierarchies, so you can access to `MyProperty`, isn't it?

Comment: unfortunately it will not as the context object will be completely different for each customer. Thanks for finding flaw in my design. This idea will simply not work and I need to create something new.

Comment: @Icen Do not hesitate to open a new question to expose your design problem and the expected result with user stories or use cases or scenario and abstraction diagrams (UML, handmade or other).